# NAT on the endpoint

Tags: nat

NAT is normally performed on the router to translate addresses from one network's address space to another's.  Is there ever a reason to perform NAT directly on the endpoint instead?

For example, if one-to-one NAT is being performed on a gateway to map private IPs from the LAN to public IPs, would there ever be a reason to perform the mapping on the endpoint itself rather than in the gateway?

Comment: You really want to avoid NAT if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Source) NAT is mostly used to provide private IP (LAN) nodes access to a public IP network (Internet). If each LAN node already had a public IP address (to potentially NAT to), they could use that for Internet access directly and wouldn't need NAT in the first place.

The main benefit of SNAT is that you can map a large number of private IPs to a single public IP (or small number of public IPs).

Remember that NAT is a kludge, and you don't use it without need.

Comment: So is your answer that "there would never be a reason to perform NAT on an endpoint?"

Comment: @Fixee Can't see a reason to use NAT like that other than the endpoint node not really being an endpoint but e.g. a VPN router (where NAT should and can be avoided but sometimes isn't).